# Populate UITableView with results of webservice

Tags: uitableview, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a table view which i want to populate with the results (XML) of my call to a web service.

The `NSURLConnection` and `NSMutableURLRequest` that are doing the setup for this are currently in my `-viewDidLoad` method, and i also have all of my UITableView delegate methods in my .m file too.

The data is being returned and added to my array correctly. My problem is (i think) that the UITableView methods are being called before any data has been returned from the web service, which is why my table view is always blank.

How can i call the methods in the right order (if this is even the problem)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling reloadData on the tableview once you've repopulated the array?  You need to let it know that you have new data.

Comment: I tried [self.listTableView reloadData] after my array was populated, but got the error "accessing unknown listTableView getter method". Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITABLEVIEW *mytableview=[[UITABLEVIEW alloc]init];
[mytableview reloadData];
```

Yes you are right; the `UITABLEVIEW` delegates are called before the web service. So you have to call those delegates again so try reloading the data. Works perfect for me. reload table when u have something returned from the webservice. store it in NSArray or whatever and then reload table.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apple's SeismicXML code example on the developer.apple.com/iphone site. It shows how to use NSURL, NSXMLParser, and a TableView to do just this type of thing.